# Enable Multiple port request of Apache2 Proxypass via Browser

Tags: node.js, apache

Enable Multiple port requests of Apache2 Proxypass with Node JS via Browser.

```
Apache2 Virtual Host

ServerName test.com
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000
ProxyPassReverse /http://localhost:8000
```

Open Chrome Browser enter test.com is Working

Open Chrome Browser enter test.com:8000 is not Working

How to make it work for both test.com:8000 and test.com at the same tme ?

Comment: Please do not format your question as code blocks if it isn't actually code.

Comment: I think you will need to setup 2 Virtual host for that

Comment: how to setup second 2 virtual host, please advise  @ashishmaurya?

Comment: I think you are using apache [https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html]

Comment: Also don't forget to enable apache on both port 80 & 8000

Comment: 8000 port is using for node js already if enable it in apache so it will conflict.